# Code with a lot of errors not sure why

Tags: java

this is the code i have so far and it isn't compiling... it is supposed to convert grayscale to character mappings... what am i missing?

```
public char[][] transform(int[][] out) {
    int row = out[0].length;
    int column = out[1].length;
    char[][] mappedImage = new char[row][column];
    for (int i= 0; i < row ;i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < column ;k++){
            if(0<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<25){
                char[i][k] == 'M';
            } else if(26<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<50){
                char [i][k] = '$';
            } else if(51<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<76){
                char [i][k] = 'o';
            } else if(77<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<102){
                char [i][k] = '|';
            } else if(103<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<127){
                char [i][k] = '*';
            } else if(128<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<152){
                char [i][k] = ':';
            } else if(153<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<178){
                char [i][k] = '=';
            } else if(179<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<204){
                char [i][k] = '\'';
            } else if(205<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<230){
                char [i][k] = '.';
            } else (231<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<255){
                char [i][k] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return mappedImage; 
}
```

Comment: post your complete code..

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd bet those pesky error messages are telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: you would be getting a lot of downvotes ,if you are not asking proper question .. read how to ask question ! welcome to stack overflow

Comment: okay wow chill...first time taking computer science i don't know anything

Answer (score 1):

Starting with...

```
char[i][k] == 'M'
```

I think you mean

```
mappedImage[i][k] == 'M'
```

Basically, `char` is reserved word and can't be used as a variable name.

Then

```
mappedImage[i][k] == 'M';
```

Which should be...

```
mappedImage[i][k] = 'M';
```

`==` is a comparison operator, you are basically saying does `mappedImage[i][k]` equal `'M'`, but not doing anything with the result, which Java does not see as a valid statement

And finally...

```
} else (231<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<255){
```

Which should be

```
} else if (231<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<255){
```

You're missing the `if` statement.  `else` basically says if nothing else, do this, but you were providing a condition after it, which was confusing the compiler

Comment: I love the courage of people who are willing to down vote questions/answers but aren't will to provide the means by which people can learn from and/or improve upon what has been posted.  Any comments on the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?
You cannot say char[x][x] = something, or char[x][x] == something,
char is a data type not a variable.

When assigning a value to a variable you need to have the variable name on the right, and the value on the left of the "=" sign, in your statements you didn't have any variable names, just a datatype.

Also, when if/else statements if takes a condition as an argument, else doesn't.

```
public char[][] transform(int[][] out) {
        int row = out[0].length;
        int column = out[1].length;
        char[][] mappedImage = new char[row][column];
        for (int i= 0; i < row ;i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < column ;k++){
                if(0<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<25){
                    mappedImage[i][k] = 'M';
                } else if(26<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<50){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = '$';
                } else if(51<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<76){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = 'o';
                } else if(77<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<102){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = '|';
                } else if(103<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<127){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = '*';
                } else if(128<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<152){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = ':';
                } else if(153<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<178){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = '=';
                } else if(179<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<204){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = '\'';
                } else if(205<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<230){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = '.';
                } else if(231<out[i][k]&&out[i][k]<255){
                    mappedImage [i][k] = ' ';
                }else{
                    //TODO whatever goes here
                }
            }
        }
        return mappedImage; 
    }
```

to print it out you need something like this:

```
for(int i =0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j =0; j < column; j++){
          System.out.println("row is: " +mappedImage[i] + "col is: " + mappedImage[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that makes much more sense.... if i want to print this in the main method then its just System.out.println(mappedImage); correct?

Comment: @user3461630 I think you'll find `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(...))` more useful. And remember `mappedImage` has local context to the `transform` method, so unless you are assign the return value from the `transform` method, you may not get the results you expect..

Comment: mappedImage is a 2D array, you cannot print an entire array at once, you need to go through it using a for loop and print each element separately.
so you need a for loop to iterate the first dimension, and the second one to iterate throughout the second dimensions.

(look at the edit of my answer for an example)

Also just a note on stackExchange, you up vote people with the answers that you find useful, and you down vote answers that are misleading. :)